# JQuery - Set checkbox inside a td to disabled?

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox, html-table

Sorry if this is obvious but have looked around and can't get this working:

```
row.find("td.favourite:first-child").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

I am struggling to select the checkbox inside the td at all, could anyone help me with this?

Comment: you need to provide some markup and html

Comment: Please paste here your HTML structure.

Comment: some code please ????????????????????

Comment: sorry for lack of html. thanks for answers all were useful for different ways of doing things but gave it to @Michael because for some reason I completely forgot to access the element via class or id!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your check box have an ID? If not or if it is unknown at design time, why not provide your check box with a CSS class - and then simply use the selector to select the class and disable the check box?

For example, if you give the check box a CSS Class of "MyCheckboxCSSClass" (which doesn't actually even have to be defined anywhere at all - make up a name if you like), you could then disable all check boxes with that class like so:

```
$(".MyCheckboxCSSClass").attr("disabled", true);
```

I am sure that will simplify the whole process for you.

Answer (score 3):

It is suggested to use `prop` instead of `attr` in these cases.
Also, adding `:checkbox` to your selector is equivalent to `[type="checkbox"]`

```
row.find('td.favorite:first-child input:checkbox').prop('disabled', true);
```

Good luck, although it will still be a better solution if you'll post your markup.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is returning the first `td` element, not the checkbox, try this:

```
row.find('td.favourite:first-child input[type="checkbox"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

This selector seems very verbose though. If you post up your HTML there is most likely a better way to traverse the DOM to get to the checkbox.